# Create dhtmlxchart line series with xAxis as muti value

Tags: xml, jsp, charts, dhtmlx

i would try to create chart using dhtmlxchart of Depth of drill from various duration data. But Depth is yAxis and multi series duration data is xAxis.

How to do that ?

```
        var chart1 = cBox.attachChart({
        view :"line",
        container: "chart_div",
        value: "#Depth#",
        line: {
                    color: "#3399ff",
                    width: 3
                },
        xAxis: {
                    title: "Duration, days",
                    template: "#Avg#"
                },
        yAxis: {
                    start: 0,
                    end: 5000,
                    step: 250,
                    title: "Depth, m"
                  }
    });

    chart1.addSeries({
        value : "#Depth#",
        line:   {
                color : "#99ff33",
                width : 3
            },
        xAxis: {
                     template: "#P90#"
                },
                });

    chart1.parse(hdrChart);
```

and the value of hdrChart is :

```
"<data>     
  <item id="1"> <Avg>0.899</Avg> <P90>3.887</P90><Depth>135</Depth> </item> 
<item id="2">   <Avg>3.981</Avg> <P90>15.845</P90>  <Depth>1550.0</Depth></item>
    <item id="3"><Avg>5.563</Avg> <P90>22.219</P90> <Depth>1550.0</Depth>   </item>
<item id="4">   <Avg>9.364</Avg><P90>44.849</P90>   <Depth>4059.0</Depth>   </item> 
<item id="5">   <Avg>9.023</Avg><P90>43.939</P90>   <Depth>4059.0</Depth>   </item>
<item id="6">   <Avg>10.919</Avg><P90>54.814</P90>  <Depth>4059.0</Depth>   </item>
<item id="7">   <Avg>14.803</Avg><P90>76.578</P90>  <Depth>4473.0</Depth>   </item>
<item id="8">   <Avg>15.691</Avg><P90>79.939</P90>  <Depth>4473.0</Depth>   </item>
<item id="9">   <Avg>17.235</Avg><P90>86.544</P90>  <Depth>4473.0</Depth>   </item>
<item id="10">  <Avg>18.264</Avg><P90>88.872</P90>  <Depth>4473.0</Depth>   </item>  </data>"
```

Only p90 drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not possibility to use different scales in one chart. And it seems that you do not need series. You may try to draw one line chart that will show Depth as value. Avg and P90 can be displayed in  xAxis labels:

```
var chart1 = cBox.attachChart({
   view :"line",
   container: "chart_div",
   value: "#Depth#",
   line: {
       color: "#3399ff",
       width: 3
   },
   xAxis: {
       title: "Duration, days",
       template: "#Avg#<br/>#P90#"
   },
   yAxis: {
       start: 0,
       end: 5000,
       step: 250,
       title: "Depth, m"
   }
});
chart1.parse(hdrChart);
```